# Word usage - Don't or No

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-request, spoken-english, writing

I often confuse myself choosing words among of 'no', 'not', "don't".

For example:

> You don't say => You not to say => you no say (?not sure)
>
> don't need your money => your money is not needed => No need your money
>
> Not required => don't required => no ?

From the examples of confusion sentences above, can anyone show me the actual mistake here and share your tips on how these words should be used properly.

Comment: It may help for you to post *complete* sentences as examples. For example, with reference to the second part of your first example, (*) "You not to say anything." sounds 'off', but "He told you not to say anything." works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must be asking which examples are complete sentences, because most of the examples you've provided are not. The most basic complete sentence must contain a *main clause*, which has both a subject and verb, and the sentence must express a complete thought. There are other requirements you can read about here: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/completesentence.htm

> You don't say => You not to say => you no say (?not sure)

***You don't say*** is the only sentence that is complete. The subject is ***you*** and the verb is ***do***. The other two examples are ungrammatical and incomplete. Both ***You not to say*** and ***You no say*** are lacking the verb *do*. In these two example, ***to say*** is not the verb. Instead, it is what is called a *bare infinitive*, meant to be preceded by the verb *do*. You can learn more about *do + bare infinitive* here: http://www.grammaring.com/do-does-did-bare-infinitive.

> don't need your money => your money is not needed => No need your money

Of these, only ***Your money is not needed*** is a complete sentence. ***Don't need your money*** and ***No need your money*** are both missing a subject (such as "I" or "we").

> Not required => don't required => no ?

None of these are actually sentences. ***Not required*** is a phrase, but it's neither a subject nor a verb. ***Don't required*** is ungrammatical, because the *do + bare infinitive* construction says that you should use the bare infinitive ***require***, not ***required***. If you're trying to make a complete sentence, you can say: ***This is not required.***

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. the links are very useful.